# Styling submit button with both text and images

Tags: html, css

I've been having trouble trying to style a submit button. I'm trying to make it an image with a red/dark red gradient and border, with the words "Search" in the middle, then a small magnifying glass right after the words "Search". Easy enough... but it needs to be able to stretch in width as the window resizes without stretching the words/magnifying glass. It also needs to work on destkop, mobile and tablet. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Is this the effect you aiming for?

```
<img width="in %">
```

demo : http://jsfiddle.net/e2qpfakq/5/

Answer (score 0):

Define width of button in percent, that will work.

```
width: 70%;
```

Use SVG image as background along with background-size: cover.

[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aaks20/sv7cfv38/1/)

Comment: But it will stretch the images

Comment: Couple of ideas, Use background-size: cover; not sure whether this will help entirely with the image in use, but the best solution to handle image responsiveness is to use an SVG image as background.